# How to join these two tables to get results as api resource?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

am having two tables one is the main client table and the other one is a sub-client table, The sub-clients is a client of the main client that is the primary key of the main client is in sub-client table how can i join these two tables and take the output in controller to pass over the resource as JSON for API ??

This is my model of the main client :

```php
 namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

        class Clients extends Model
            {
                  //
                    }
```

This is my Controller of the main client :

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Clients;
    use App\Http\Resources\Client as ClientResource;

        // use Illuminate\Http\Response;

    class Clients_controller extends Controller
        {
          /**
             * Display a listing of the resource.
           *
            * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
         public function index()
          {
                   //get clients

                       $clients = Clients::paginate(15);

                   //Return collection of clients as a resource
                   return ClientResource::collection($clients);
              }
                    }
```

This is my model of the Sub client :

```php
 namespace App;

            use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

            class Sub_clients extends Model
            {
                //
            }
```

This is my Controller of the sub-client :

```php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

            use Illuminate\Http\Request;
            use App\Sub_clients;
            use App\Http\Resources\Sub_client as SubclientResource;

            class Sub_client extends Controller
            {
               /**
               * Display a listing of the resource.
              *
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
              */
          public function index()
           {
                //get Sub_clients

                 $subclients = Sub_clients::paginate(15);

                 //Return collection of sub clients as a resource
                  return SubclientResource::collection($subclients);
             }
                }
```

Can anyone please help since am new to laravel

Comment: Can you specify an example of what the data returned in the API should be?

Comment: already got the answer, appreciate the support

Comment: Can you share your answer? Someone might run into a similar situation on the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I joined using Query Builder

```
  $client = DB::table('clients')
          ->join('sub_clients', 'clients.c_id', '=', 'sub_clients.c_id')  
          ->select('clients.*', 'sub_clients.password', 'sub_clients.username as name')
          ->where('sub_clients.c_id','=',$c_id)
          ->get();
```